# Elasticsearch terms and cardinality aggregations returns different results

Tags: elasticsearch, unique, aggregation, distinct-values, cardinality

I'm new to Elastic Search and wondering about a issue I encountered while playing with aggregations. 
I have an index of IP details and I want to get the number of distinct IP addresses. To do this, I first used a terms aggregation with the following query:

```
GET /myIndex/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "ip": {
         "terms": {
            "size": 0,
            "field": "sender"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This query returned 59082 buckets, which means 59082 distinct IP addresses.

Then I used the cardinality aggregation with the following query:

```
GET /myIndex/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "ip" : {
            "cardinality" : {
                "field" : "sender"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This one returned 58837 distinct IP addresses.

I'm wondering if I did something wrong on the queries or this is an internal issue of Elastic Search (maybe the loss of precision since all shards return the top results in terms aggregation?)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to specify a [`precision_threshold`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html#_precision_control) in your `cardinality` aggregation with a high value (say the max supported is 40000)? Are the results better?

Comment: Oh, I saw it in the documentation and everything is more clear now: 
A single-value metrics aggregation that calculates an approximate count of distinct values. Values can be extracted either from specific fields in the document or generated by a script.
@Val, when I increased the precision threshold, I got more precise results. Thanks!